# Synonym for "dragged on"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for **dragged on**.

For example:

```
This project has dragged on and needs to be completed.

His story was very long, it just dragged on.
```

I have used **languished** in the past, although I don't think that is correct usage.

Comment: The past tense of "to drag" is "dragged" not "drug".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protract is a decent word choice. To [protract](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/protracted) is:

> To draw out or lengthen in time; prolong: disputants who needlessly protracted the negotiations.

To fit your two suggested sentences, I would re-word them as follows:

> This project has been protracted and needs to be completed.
>
> His story was very long, and it protracted for what seemed like forever.

Answer (score 0):

**on and on** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+and+on) an idiom

> continuously and perpetually, without stopping.

As in:

*His story went **on and on**.*